# Como procesar el contenido de un json a un store procedure en oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente formato del json

```
{
   "campo1":"1000120220111",
   "nombre":X0X0X0 XX000X XX000",
   "deviceList":[
       {
         "id_dispositivo":"000000122",
         "nombre:"T1-12300000",
         "numeroserie":"DERXZC-RFGDA-00"
       },
       {
         "id_dispositivo":"000000122",
         "nombre:"T1-12300000",
         "numeroserie":"DERXZC-RFGDA-00"
       }
    ],

   "vehiculoList":[
      
       {
         "id_vehiculo":"000000122",
         "nombre:"T1-12300000",
         "numeroserie":"DERXZC-RFGDA-00"
       },
       {
         "id_vehiculo":"000000122",
         "nombre:"T1-12300000",
         "numeroserie":"DERXZC-RFGDA-00"
       }
    ]
}
```

Como se muestra en el ejemplo para procesar esta información a una base de datos de oracle, se podría dividir en 3 tablas, Tabla 1: información general, Tabla 2: información de dispositivos, tabla 3: información de vehículos.

Estas tablas desde java seria una inserción secuencial donde estaría llamando 3 veces el preparedStatement para insertar en las 3 tablas para un solo registro, por lo tanto hacer este tipo registro a una base de datos es muy lento ya que llego a demorar como 4 horas registrando 1Millon de json y usando hasta multiprocesos,

Podría mejorar la carga si hiciera un store procedure y procesar un registro de un json hacia  el store procedure  o enviar una lista de la información del json, pero no estoy seguro como implementar esto.

Estuve investigando sobre object en oracle, donde en java podría convertir una lista de datos a objectos y desde oracle hacer las inserciones, sin tener que hacerlo desde java

A lo que me refiero es hacer algo similar en un store precedure(solo es un ejemplo):

```
for usuario user in listaUsuario
    
       insert into tabla_users... // cargar la información general
    
       for dispositivo device in deviceList
          insert into tabla_devices... // cargar informacion de los dispositivos del usuario
       end 
       
       
       for vehiculo v in vehiculosList
          insert into tabla_vehiculos... // cargar informacion de los vehiculo al usuario
       end 
    
    end
```

de esta manera no estaría haciendo tantas operaciones de llamada para cada insert desde java, sino que mandaría la información de del json convertido a object y desde un store procedure hacer las inserciones con el forloop, tanto podría insertar por lotes o insertar un json de uno por uno, pero no tengo idea si esto es posible hacerlo desde oracle.

Lo único que quiero es convertir el formato del json y enviarlo a un store procedure y desde ahí hacer las inserciones.

Espero y me supe explicar, ya que nunca lo había hecho y no tengo idea de como se hace, si alguien tiene información y me apoya con algunas ideas, se los agradecería.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, ya te puse un ejemplo sencillo, mas tarde te comparto uno de como leer tu json

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto 2 links donde viene algo de json solo no olvides revisar tu version de Oracle, el ejemplo comenta la 12

https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/how-to-pass-json-type-data-as-an-input-parameter-in-a-store-2257

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_GAYINRPNAY5EYANPGZ704WX93.html

Te comparto un ejemplo de como sería el sp

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procesar_json (p_json IN CLOB) AS
  v_value VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  -- Extraer el valor de una propiedad JSON
  v_value := JSON_VALUE(p_json, '$.Name');

  -- Tu lógica adicional de procesamiento aquí
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Nombre: ' || v_value);
  NULL;
END;
```

y para llamarlo así

```
DECLARE
  v_json CLOB;
BEGIN
  -- Asigna tu JSON a la variable
  v_json := '{"Name":"Elvis"}';

  -- Llama al Stored Procedure
  procesar_json(v_json);
END;
```

Quedo al pendiente de tu avance
Saludos!!

Comment: Está bien incluir links a otros recursos en una respuesta, pero la parte central que responde la respuesta debe incluirse como parte de la misma, pues los links pueden estar rotos en el futuro y se perdería el aporte. Para más información visita [answer].

Comment: Entiendo, si fue una respuesta rapida, estoy trabajando en la parte central, saludos!